# A main checkbox that enable others checkbox

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

Hello i dont know how to made a **checkbox** that **activate** anothers checks box in a excel 2010.

[image]

What I mean If i check the first checkbox made falso al the other checkbox.

Comment: You'll need to add code to the click event of each check box to call a method that sets the value of the other checkboxes

Comment: Thanks, that solve my problem i think with `Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()`

Comment: @JonathanRaulTapiaLopez submit your own answer in that case)

Answer (score 3):

short example here. Add check box named MasterCheckBox to your form. Use UserFormEnableEvents to suppres events in user form ... if u need.

```
Option Explicit
Private UserFormEnableEvents As Boolean

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  UserFormEnableEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub MasterCheckBox_Change(): On Error GoTo Err_handler
  Dim userFormControl As Control

  UserFormEnableEvents = False

  For Each userFormControl In Me.Controls
    If (TypeOf userFormControl Is MSForms.CheckBox And _
      userFormControl.Name <> MasterCheckBox.Name) Then
        userFormControl.Value = Not userFormControl.Value
    End If
  Next

Err_handler:
  If (Err.Number <> 0) Then MsgBox Err.Description
  UserFormEnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: +1. If you, or anybody, are interested in "two-way" checkboxes, where clicking one of the group checkboxes also effects the master, I wrote this post: http://yoursumbuddy.com/userform-event-handler-class-multiple-controls/.